# Ecto SQL Fragment fails, why?

Tags: sql, elixir, ecto

Trying to execute SQL fragment:

```
Repo.all from p in Posts, where: fragment("lower(?) in ?", p.title, ^["some-title"])
```

But it fails, it generates following SQL and the error:

```
SELECT p0."title" FROM "posts" AS p0 WHERE (lower(p0."title") in $1) [["some-title"]]

** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (syntax_error): syntax error at or near "$1"
```

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

So, after lots of trials I figured out how to use it:

```
Repo.all from p in Posts, where: fragment("lower(?)", p.title) in ^["some-title"])
```

But still - **why the original expression didn't worked? It seems like it's completely valid too.**

**UPDATE**

> There should be parentheses after `in`

I tried it, didn't works either:

```
Repo.all from p in Posts, where: fragment("lower(?) in (?)", p.title, ^["some-title"])

** (ArgumentError) Postgrex expected a binary that can be encoded/cast to type "text", got ["some-title"]. Please make sure the value you are passing matches the definition in your table or in your query or convert the value accordingly.
```

Comment: There should be parentheses after `in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, the right way to go is:

```
Repo.all from p in Posts, where: fragment("lower(?)", p.title) in ["some-title"])
```

2) The original query does not work because it generates wrong SQL syntax.
It generates something like:

```
... where lower(p.title) in ["some-title"] ...
```

where the right syntax is:

```
... where lower(p.title) in ('some-title') ...
```